# how to make a chat room on gae ,has any audio python-framework to do this?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, audio, chat

i want to make a chat room on gae ,(audio chat)

has any framework to do this  ?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

App Engine doesn't directly support audio chat of any sort, and since it's based around a request-response system with (primarily) HTTP requests, you can't implement it yourself.

Comment: So you can't have the app initiate a HTTP session and hold it open while the client and server stream HTTP messages back and forth?

Comment: I presume you mean an HTTP connection, since there's no such thing as an HTTP session. No, App Engine doesn't give you any control over the underlying connection - and I'm not sure what it would buy you in any case.

Answer (score 1):

Try Adobe Stratus (it works with p2p connections) and you could use Google App Engine only for exchanging peer ids.

Answer (score 0):

If you support [Jingle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jingle_%28protocol%29) then all you have to do is pass the XMPP packets around. There's lots of modules that support that.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need two things:

A browser plugin to get audio. You could build this on top of eg. http://code.google.com/p/libjingle/'>libjingle which has the advantage of being cross-platform and allowing P2P communication, not to mention being able to talk to arbitrary other XMPP endoints. Or you could use Flash to grab the audio and bounce the stream off a server you build (I think trying to do STUN in Flash for P2P would be impossible), but this would be very tricky to do in App Engine because you'd need it to be long-running.

A way to get signaling messages between your clients. You'll have to poll until the Channel API is released (soon).

This is a big hairy problem, to put it mildly, but it would be *awesome* if you did it.

Comment: It doesn't need to be a browser per se, it just needs some sort of application that talks HTTP.